# Android snackbar looks to be attached to a nested scrollview

Tags: android

I have a weird problem where the `Snackbar` is being attached to the scroll view, so when a user scrolls the snackbar moves with the scrolling instead of staying position on the bottom of the screen.

I know it's caused by how I've set up my layout but I don't know a solution to either better setup my layout, or stop this behavior.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            style="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutMediumStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/collapsingToolbarLayoutMediumSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:title="" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see I'm wrapping the `FragmentContainerView` inside of a `NestedScrollView` which works and allows the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to work as expected, as well as the child fragments content to scroll as I want.

Each child fragment just implements a basic layout a bit like:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

   //... Lots of text views etc etc

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I tried removing the top level `NestedScrollView` and implementing it at each fragment, but that caused lots of issues with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and the child fragment content overlapping etc.

Is there a more straightforward solution to this?

Thanks for any input

Comment: Why you need nested scroll here... You can include inside fragment itself... Here add your container only.

Comment: I tried that, but as per my question then the CollapsingToolbarLayout breaks and no longer collapse, as well as clips through the content.